# What is android:supportsRtl attribute in AndroidManifest

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-manifest

What is the attribute android:supportsRtl="true" ?

This is my AndroidManifest

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#supportsrtl

Answer (score 4):

It gives you RTL support which means mirror effect for devices have local languages orientation from right to left, such as Arabic, Persian etc.

In order to give that feature to your application you should follow the steps in the link below.

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html